# How to update Plotly scatter by filtering pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I have created a scatter plot in plotly. Now I would like update the plot by selecting a dropdown element in plotly. This should filter the source dataframe by values in one column. I am almost there but formatting of the axis is wrong:

May dataframe - aircraft for different airlines and dates...

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id':['AC1', 'AC2', 'AC3', 'AC4'],
    'airline':['DLH', 'DLH', 'DAL', 'DAL'],
    'date1' :pd.date_range('2017-02-24', periods=4, freq='M'),
    'date2' :pd.date_range('2018-02-24', periods=4, freq='M'),
    'date3' :pd.date_range('2019-02-24', periods=4, freq='M'),
    'date4' :pd.date_range('2020-02-24', periods=4, freq='M')
    })
```

I create a scatterplot with traces for the date columns:

```
fig = go.Figure()
traces = ['date1', 'date2', 'date3', 'date4']
for trace in traces:
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(
            x=df[trace],
            y=df['id'],
            mode="markers",
            name=trace
        )
    )
```

[initial scatter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8bkZ.png)

Now the part where I struggle - I want to select an airline in the dropdown and this should update the plot, showing only the aircraft for the specific airline. I have managed to get the dots but x- and y-axis are not formatted properly. They should be the same as in the initial plot. X-axis as date, Y-axis as categorical values (ac_id)

```
buttons = []
for airline in df['airline'].unique():
    buttons.append(dict(method='restyle',
                        label=airline,
                        args=[{
                        'x': df[df['airline'] == airline][traces].T.values,
                        'y': df[df['airline'] == airline]['id'].tolist()
                        }])
                    )
```

[filtered scatter - wrong axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqDo5.png)

Last some menu adjusting and printing the plot:

```
updatemenu=[]
menu=dict()
updatemenu.append(menu)
updatemenu[0]['buttons']=buttons
updatemenu[0]['direction']='down'
updatemenu[0]['showactive']=True

fig.update_layout(updatemenus=updatemenu)
fig.show()
```

Comment: It would help if you described how you want the x- and y-axes to appear. Should they be like they are in the initial scatter plot you linked? Something else?

Comment: thanks fo the remark. I changed it in the description. Should be like in the initial plot.

Comment: I ran your code in my environment and didn't get the funny results you asked about. My environment is the latest version 5.6.0.

Comment: works fine for me too... a couple of comments 1. **update** is not really correct method fort this. it should be **restyle** you are only changing data attributes.  2.  is there anything else you are doing in defining layout,  clearly your screen image is seconds from epoch, which would happen if you change xaxis details

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

Formatting of the X-Axis seems to be a version issue. With Plotly 5.6.0 it works just fine.

The Y-Axis was due to the wrong size of the array:
I changed it to match the x-values shape with numpy.tile:

```
np.tile(df[df['airline'] == airline]['id'].T.values, (4,1))
```